Microsoft API Application Permissions - List all Tenants / Future Deprecated APIs Unclear
At the moment I want to use the Graph API for an application that will list all the tenants, get all users per tenant and then list all their licenses. Due to circumstances I can only use the web calls, no Powershell modules or any of the sort.
I found that you should be able to do this in Graph (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/managedtenants-managedtenant-list-tenants?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) except it's only allowed for delegated permissions and in the beta.
So I searched for an alternative for which seemed to be the management.azure.com API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list?view=rest-resources-2022-12-01&tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) but I can't for the life of me figure if this one is getting deprecated alongside all the other recent API stuff getting deprecated. I'm also not clear if this one is only delegated permissions aswell.
Can you guys confirm? Or any other tips to get the functionality what I need? Many thanks

Is your requirement is to use only Application API permissions?

The Azure Service Management API has only delegated permission but you can make use of client credential flow to generate token and get the tenants

It is not a hard requirement, but a very big preference. It's to use with automation that inputs the api data in a local database. Delegated permissions would require logging in all the time to run it. Also, can you confirm for me if the management.azure.com api is being deprecated, like the Powershell modules for example? Or is it a different system? @Rukmini

No need to login instead use client credential flow

So if I use client credential flow I'm able to run the API Call whenever, without having to intervene / login for delegated permissions? Can I also use this with Graph and Graph's beta? Or do I have to mix with Azure Management API?

You have use  Azure Management API and Can I post it as an answer?

Sure, if you can confirm for me if the Azure Management API is being deprecated / replaced by Graph. Otherwise it won't be wise for me to use it.

AFAIK only versions will be updated the Azure Service management API won't be deprecated.

To list the tenants without user interaction, check the below:
Create a Microsoft Entra ID application and grant API permissions:

Generate the access token via Client Credential flow:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


By using the above access token, you can call the API to list the tenants:
https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01



Alright, I will be trying this out. Thanks!

I was able to successfully get the token and call the API, but the call only returns the same tenant that the application is registered in. Not all the tenants I can see when going to Microsoft 365 Admin Center or using the Graph Explorer with a global admin account.

Yes because in Graph Explorer its a user interactive flow it lists tenants for user account but if you want to use non-interactive flow then it only lists the tenant application is part off

If you want the tenants for user then you have to use interactive flow only or ROPC flow  which authenticates the user without interaction. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc

What is the recommended way to list all the tenants with a non-interactive application flow? Or as I asked before; is that a thing that's just not possible without having to login with a priviliged account? Thanks in advance. (Just saw the updated comment, I'll read it.)

Is ROPC flow suitable for you? which is non interactive you need to pass username and password directly while generating the token

@Bryant ROPC flow doesnt redirect to browser for user login is that okay for you?

Hi, yeah that should be fine. I setup Postman with ROPC, using the same account credentials that I can see all tenants with on the 365 admin portal. Within the app api permissions I also set "ManagedTenants.Read.All" for Graph. I tried the Beta graph, but it says I don't have authorization. And when trying "https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01" it only lists the single tenant again. Both use the .default scope.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
